# Neo4j Dynamic cql switching

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I want to switch database based on a request header, which I have managed to do but in a rather clunky way.

1. I had to change my jdbc driver to neo native driver to get the "USE database" prefix to work.
2. I had to prefix my cql query with "USE database "

What I really want is to do this via AOP, such that I can annotate the method with my custom java annotation and this aspect will just call "USE DATABASE" in isolation before going on to the joinpoint and calling the actual query.

When I try this though I get this error

*Query cannot conclude with USE GRAPH (must be RETURN or an update clause)*

Is it possible ?

Comment: please show us your code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the database on the session object.

```
try (Session session = driver.session(SessionConfig.forDatabase( "databaseName" ))) {
   session.executeWrite((tx) -> tx.run(stmt, params));
}
```

You shouldn't use JDBC for apps, that's rather for tools.

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-manual/current/cypher-workflow/#java-database-selection